# let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called a special vector for A, if $Av=v$, and is called untrivial special vector if $v\ne0$. 
 
Prove that:
 $A$ has an untrivial special vector if and only if $A^t$ (transpose) has an untrivial special vector. 
 
My attempt: I said that let $v$ be an untrivial special vector for $A$, then $Av=v$, then I did transpose on all equation sides and got $v^tA^t=v^t$. 
 I really think that this is the same as $A^tv=v$ (tried a couple examples), but I can't somehow prove it. maybe because im wrong or because I just didn't succeed at it. 
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't prove it because it's not true. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Chrystomath You should be more specific: the attempt fails, but the claim is true.

Comment: You must really specify what you may or may not use for the proof, otherwise you get the answer "it is obvious as $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues". Would you be satisfied with that?

Comment: @A.Γ. It's not clear whether the question is the "Prove that:" or "I really think that this is the same..."

Comment: "Untrivial special vector" is basically an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. The eigenvector will exist iff $A$ has $1$ as its eigenvalue. Your statement is reduced to proving: $A$ has eigenvalue $1$ iff $A^T$ has eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Do you know [Rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)?

Comment: @A.Γ. I actually just learned it today. I'm really sorry that I didn't specify using what material I want, I just didn't know what to use to solve it or what is needed, I know that I can use every material I learnt until invertible matrices, but I also got an answer about determinants that I think helped me in solving the question. I will try to be more specific next time

Comment: A quick run then: let $B=A-I$, we have $\exists v\ne 0\colon Bv=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall u\colon u^TBv=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall u\colon B^Tu\bot v$ $\Rightarrow$ $\operatorname{rank}B^T<n$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists u\colon B^Tu=0$. The last implication from Rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\det(I-A)= \det((I-A)^t)= \det(I-A^t).$$

Then it follows that

$A$  has an untrivial special vector $ \iff \det(I-A)=0 \iff \det(I-A^t)=0 \iff A^t$ has an untrivial special vector

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to be honest the question is supposed to be solved without using det yet, but I think that I got the idea, if the equation $(I-A)x=0$ has an untrivial solution then $Ax=x$ has an untrivial solution. did I understand it correctly?